# Docker Windows Compose Traefik

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, traefik, docker-for-windows

Hej,

I am trying to install Traefik on my docker system (Docker for Windows with gui and Portainer). Now I should create the traefik.yml and transfer it via volumes.

This is what the tutorial says:

```
volumes:
  - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
```

I tried to create a volume called `traefik`

```
    volumes:
      traefik:
```

Path in the Windows machine to the Volumes folder:

`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes`

How can I retrieve the traefik.yml file in this volume now? Unfortunately, that's not how it works:

```
volumes:
   - traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
```

Best regards

I've tried a lot and unfortunately I haven't been successful. I can't get the traefik.yml into the system

Answer (score 0):

in the *.yml* file these tags:

```
    volumes:
 - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
```

mean that you are binding your local file located at *./data/traefik.yml* to the file stored on the container at */traefik.yml*, with read only access *:ro*.

If you want to edit the static configuration of traefik, you have to modify the file located at *./data/traefik.yml*.
When running docker, you can check if the traefik container is using this file as configuration by inspecting the container logs.

Comment: I have to create the file myself to fill it with data to configure Traefik. Where do I find myself in Docker Windows when I type this. `./data/traefik.yml`

The problem is I have to put the file somewhere to load it. Unfortunately, there are only tutorials that are designed for Linux Docker, not for Windows Docker.

Comment: in linux _./_ meas that you are usign the path  _/data/traefik.yml_ starting from the actual location.
Here: 
`volumes:
 - [some-path]:/traefik.yml:ro`
you can also specify an absolute path.
In your case the file _./data/traefik.yml_ is located in the folder data wrt the point where you run docker deamon